# Converting storyboard to xib that In order to support iOS4.x

Tags: ios5, ios4, storyboard

Well,I created a project with storyboard,but I realized storyboards were only compatible on iOS 5,its not support iOS4.3. Is there anyway I could get it working on iOS 4 by automatic or manual converting them to XIB's somehow?